# Android: Problem with OnItemClickListener

Tags: android

I am a beginner Android developer. I am trying to create an SMS application.

I have created a `TabHost` with three `TabSpect(ListView,ListView,TextView)` which prints me `INBOX`, `Send` and in `TextView` it prints some useful information.

Now if I am trying to click on any item in `ListView`, it will open the SMS manager, where it will be filled with the `phoneNumber` of the SMS I clicked.

Every time I try this I receive an error.

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg, View view, int position,long id) {

    Uri uriSMSURIs = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    String pos = String.valueOf(position);
    Log.d(TAG, "value: " + pos);
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURIs, null, pos, null, null);

    Log.e(TAG, "value: " + c);
    String phoneNumber  = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"));
    Log.e(TAG, "Value: " + phoneNumber;

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    sendIntent.putExtra("address", phoneNumber);
    sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
  }
});
```

`pos` is returning the position of the selected item but if I use `pos` in

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURIs, null, pos, null, null);
```

it throws this error:

> 04-02 07:53:15.504: ERROR/SMSManager(328): value: android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@43e2b800.

I dont know if I can do that this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the parameters you're passing to the query are the wrong types. Try this:

```
long id = arg.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURIs, null, "_id = ?", new String[]{Long.toString(id)}, null);
```

See the documentation for [ContentResolver.query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: That is returning same value as my variable pos. ( String pos = String.valueOf(position);) So it didn't work and I have already read documentation for ContentResolver..Have you got any other ideas?

Comment: You tried it with the third parameter set to "_id = ?" and it still didn't work? In your initial example you were passing 'pos' into the 'selection' parameter of query(), instead of into the 'selectionArgs' parameter.

Comment: Yes,but i added Log.d(TAG, "Value of: " + id) and it is returning same value as pos

Comment: Witch premissions must i have?