# Android: How to save entry to the calendar automaticly

Tags: android

How can i save entry to the calendar automaticly?If i use this source code,it opens Calendar with filled entrys, but i must click on save button to save it.

Source code:

```
 while (callCur.moveToNext()){
            String Number = callCur.getString(callCur.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));

            Log.d(TAG, "Value of Number: " + Number);

            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");

            intent.putExtra ("title", Number);
            intent.putExtra ("description", "test2");
            intent.putExtra ("eventLocation", "somewhere");
            intent.putExtra ("beginTime", System.currentTimeMillis () + 60 * 60 * 1000);
            intent.putExtra ("endTime", System.currentTimeMillis () + 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000);


            startActivity(intent);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that code simply opens the Calendar activity with some pre-loaded data. To save an event to the calendar without having to force the user to use you will need to use a different API. Here's a tutorial on [accessing the Android calendar API](http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/3850276/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar.htm). And [another](http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=151).

You can still launch the activity after creating an event to show it to the user.

Comment: You're quite welcome. And welcome to SO if you haven't received one yet. ;-) Btw, if you like my answer you can throw additional rep points my way by clicking the up arrow on the left side of the answer. It's all in the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I like to click on the up arrow, but i need atleast 15 rep :(

Comment: Lol. Looks like I need to revisit the FAQ myself! It's been a while.

Comment: Can i have another answer? i will make new post ok?It's about onItemCLickListener

Comment: check this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521963/android-problem-with-onitemclicklistener

Comment: **WARNING**: The approaches outlined in this answer do not use public APIs. They are hacks that rely on implementation details. If you build an app using this it may very well stop working on a future version of Android, or on devices that use a calendar app different from the stock open source version!

Comment: @adamp: I should have mentioned that the apis are not officially documented but I would not necessarily call them hacks. Is the a better, official option?

Comment: Unfortunately the official way to do this right now is to talk directly to Google Calendar's web APIs. (Yes, we're well aware that this isn't ideal.)